# .htaccess is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Tags: .htaccess

I have URLs in this format

`site.com/brochure/12/subcat/subcat/maincat`

The only important part of the string to my application is the number directly after brochure
There can sometimes be many `subcat` false directories so I've had to use many rules like these to make it work

`RewriteRule ^brochure/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ brochure.php?cat_path=$1`
`RewriteRule ^brochure/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ brochure.php?cat_path=$1`
`RewriteRule ^brochure/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ brochure.php?cat_path=$1`

etc etc - sometimes up to five different rules to allow for the different directory structures.

I'm guessing this can be done in a single rule, anyone kind enough to share their ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't care about any part of the string after your initial `([^/]+)`, why not just use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^brochure/([^/]+).*$ brochure.php?cat_path=$1
```

This will match and group your `12`, then quietly match and discard the remainder of the string (`.*$`).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thanks :) Also, my application is noticeably quicker now when skips through pages.